# CSS Background image repeat issue

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to have a background image repeat x and y to the bottom of the page.

The background image pattern div is

```
#pattern {    
    height: 3000px;
    width: 1000px;
    background:url(../images/patterns/pattern1.jpg) repeat;
    }
```

In the html, it resides inside

```
#wrapper {    
    position: relative;    
    width: 1000px;    
    margin: 0 auto;    
    text-align: left;    
    }
```

The height on #pattern is set to 3000px just so it will show up, otherwise the image will not appear.

I have tried various things such as:

```
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
overflow: auto;
```

I would like the background image to repeat to the bottom of #wrapper, to the bottom of the page.

Webpage is here:

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You've set a fixed height on the wrapper, so it'll stop at 3000px, regardless of how much content is in there. Try a min-height instead. That'll keep it at a minimum size so it's visible,but allows it to grow to fit the content in it.

Comment: I've contained the content within #pattern (which is contained inside of #wrapper). I've also changed the height to min-height; 100%; but I seem to have the same problem, the image is background image is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the #pattern a `position:fixed;` so it doesn't matter how much content you have to scroll, it won't scroll itself.

Comment: That pretty much works, but I'd like to have the background image scroll with the rest of the content, if possible. 

With position:fixed, the background image is static.

Comment: In that case why not just assign the background-image to the #wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Side note: repeat is the default property for background image so no need to declare.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is wrong. The #pattern div should **contain** the rest of the page. You want it to grow with the contents.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and did this. I've kept #pattern within the #wrapper div since I don't want #pattern to exceed that area.

Answer (score 0):

Your interior divs are all absolutely positioned, making it impossible for them to influence the height of the container #wrapper, which is where you'd want to put your background image code.

Also, I'm not sure if this is intentional, but #pattern doesn't wrap any of your content, so it's height has to be manually set, since it has no children.

There are two approaches you can take. Use Javascript to determine the combined height of your absolutely positioned divs and set the height of the pattern to that number.

Or, you can use float to arrange your columns, and put a

at the end to force the parent container to be that tall.

Comment: I've wrapped the #pattern div around the content now. Sounds like floating the divs may be the best idea. Can the site still retain the same width if the columns are floated? I'd like to have the columns in the same position on the page and not be moving around. I've never done a floating .div so I'm not sure what to expect.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Set a fixed width of your parent div and the floats will automagically line up next to eachother, filling the space. Set a background-color to see the DOM boxes, and play around, and you'll under stand floats soon enough. Remember to "clear" them when you're done with "clear:both" css style on a block element (p or div) if this helps, please mark answered :)

Answer (score 0):

The **div** tag containing the **#pattern** style should start on the first line after the **body** tag and close at the end of the page just before the close of the **body** tag.

BTW, **remove** the **height** and **width** attributes or set it to **100%** so that it repeats throughout the page.